# Can you add an additional row in Active Admin when using `index do`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm simply trying to add a spacer `<tr>` into my table.

My setup looks as so :

```
index do
  column :id
  column :name
end
```

And I would like to an additional row or  per table row that would act as a spacer for cosmetic purposes.

Is this possible? Or do I need to gut out my entire model and redo it as something like this :

```
content do
  table id: 'my_table' do
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add a row for "cosmetic purposes" (it's semantically incorrect, that's why we have styles instead). I don't think there is a way to adding a class to the row (`<tr>`) in ActiveAdmin, so you will have to do something like this:

```
column :id do |id|
  div class: 'new_section' do 
    id  
  end
end
```

Where you add this class to the first row of each "section" and have a style. This will increase the size of the height, and hopefully the row.

```
div.new_section { height: 100px; }
```